# JDK 6 Calendar October 20 2041 BUG

Tags: java, calendar

We get a bug in our system: when we set the date to October, 20, 2041, we set the date to
October, 19, 2041 - 23 hs

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(2041, Calendar.OCTOBER, 20, 0, 0, 0);
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Output:

```
Sat Oct 19 23:00:00 BRT 2041
```

This behavior happens when we use JDK 6, in JDK 7 the output is correct:

```
Sat Oct 20 00:00:00 BRT 2041
```

But we cannot use the jdk 7 in our system. Anyone have more information about this bug?

--
more information: this happens only on dates after 2040

Comment: Out of interest, is it giving the wrong result just when you output a Brasilia Time (ie if you output as UTC what result do you get)? And if it is a bug specific to JDK6 and you can't use JDK7 but can use external libraries you may find joda time works(?)

Comment: If you have to stick with version 6 you should pay Oracle for fixing the bug as part of a support contract (if it is a bug) since JDK 6 is out of public support now

Comment: If you observe a different behaviour in JDK7 then the reason might be a different timezone data repository. Try the [TZ-Updater-Tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) from Oracle to update your repository.

Comment: when I set to UTC he set the time to -3 hours the (BRT is GMT +3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Time Zone & DST Data Changes

The [answer by GriffeyDog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24070029/642706) and comments suggest you are confused because of settings on your computer and JVM. The problem is probably related to [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) as October 20 is around the time of [DST change for Brazil](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/brazil/brasilia). The [data for time zones and DST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) is updated along with updates to Java. You may be seeing a difference between updates for Brazil.

## Joda-Time

Test this out by using the current version (now 2.3) of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). Much less confusing than using java.util.Date & .Calendar. A DateTime in Joda-Time knows its own assigned time zone. Joda-Time works in both Java 6 & 7 (and 8). Joda-Time contains its own time zone and DST data rather than using the data bundled with Java.

## Use UTC

As one of the comments suggests, use UTC explicitly to compare.

## Example Code in Joda-Time

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneSao_Paulo = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Sao_Paulo" );

DateTime dateTimeSao_Paulo = new DateTime( 2041, DateTimeConstants.OCTOBER, 20, 1, 2, 3, timeZoneSao_Paulo ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTimeSao_Paulo.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );

DateTime dateTimeSao_PauloBeforeMidnight = new DateTime( 2041, DateTimeConstants.OCTOBER, 19, 23, 50, 0, timeZoneSao_Paulo );
DateTime dateTimeSao_PauloAfterMidnight = dateTimeSao_PauloBeforeMidnight.plusHours( 1 );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "dateTimeSao_Paulo: " + dateTimeSao_Paulo );
System.out.println( "dateTimeUtc: " + dateTimeUtc );
System.out.println( "dateTimeSao_PauloBeforeMidnight: " + dateTimeSao_PauloBeforeMidnight );
System.out.println( "dateTimeSao_PauloAfterMidnight: " + dateTimeSao_PauloAfterMidnight );
```

When run.

```
dateTimeSao_Paulo: 2041-10-20T01:00:00.000-02:00
dateTimeUtc: 2041-10-20T03:00:00.000Z
dateTimeSao_PauloBeforeMidnight: 2041-10-19T23:50:00.000-03:00
dateTimeSao_PauloAfterMidnight: 2041-10-20T01:50:00.000-02:00
```

Experiment by working with the day before and adding hours via the `plusHours` method.

As you can in that output above, **Midnight October 19-20 of 2041** is the currently scheduled date for a DST change, with the offset from UTC shifting from `-03:00` to `-02:00`. Adding *one hour* to before-midnight jumped the [wall-clock-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) *two hours*, from `23` hours to `01` hours rather than `00` hours.

Furthermore, note that trying to construct a time of 00:00:00 on the 20th results in a Joda-Time exception because there is no such date-time.

## Date From Database

The [`getDate` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getDate%28int%29) of a JDBC ResultSet returns a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) which is a bastardized version of a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Neither java.sql.Date nor java.util.Date contain time zone information, but are assumed to be UTC. The difference between them is that the `sql` version has its time value set to 00:00:00 (midnight) in a poor attempt to match the [SQL data type DATE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Date_and_time). In SQL, DATE means date-only with no time-of-day. Unfortunately old versions of Java and JDBC have no date-only class, but should have. That has been rectified in [Java 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29) with [the java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and its [`LocalDate` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), but JDBC has not yet caught up.

So if you get a java.sql.Date from a database, you must consult the programmers or database administrators to confirm if that date-time is indeed meant to UTC. It *should* be, but proper date-time work eludes many programmers and admins, so you should verify.

If the java.sql.Date is indeed UTC, then convert to Joda-Time by passing it to a DateTime constructor. I strongly recommend also passing a DateTimeZone to be assigned to the new DateTime, rather than rely on the JVM's default time zone being assigned.

```
DateTime dateTimeFromDatabaseBrazil = new DateTime( myJavaSqlDate, timeZoneSao_Paulo );
```

or

```
DateTime dateTimeFromDatabaseUtc = new DateTime( myJavaSqlDate, DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

If you assign to a non-UTC time zone, you may want to adjust the time portion to the first moment of the day in that locality for consistency with the idea of focusing on the date rather than time-of-day. To get first moment, call [`withTimeAtStartOfDay` method](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay%28%29) (new in Joda-Time 2.3, with old "midnight" classes and methods being deprecated).

```
DateTime dateTimeFromDatabaseBrazil = new DateTime( myJavaSqlDate, timeZoneSao_Paulo ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
```

Or convert to a [`LocalDate`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html) object if you are certain you want date-only without time of day.

Comment: my problem is that I get the Date from Database with resultSet.getDate (...). Then the date will be create wrong just here.

Comment: @alexpfb Your question about getting a date from database has been asked and answered many times on StackOverflow, but nevertheless I added my take on the subject by adding a section at the end of my answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Is your local/default time zone an hour earlier than "BRT"?

Try using `SimpleDateFormat` to output your date. This works for me in US Central Time, setting "BRT" as the time zone to use.

```
  public static void main(String... args) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BRT"));
    c.set(2041, Calendar.OCTOBER, 20, 0, 0, 0);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BRT"));
    System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
    System.out.println(c.getTime());
  }
```

Comment: This was my thought too.

Comment: I guess it's Brasilia Summer Time on the poster's PC?

Comment: That would be my guess.

Comment: I find whenever time is doing weird things that it pays to work in UTC and confirm things before converting to a local time. We have had problems with code here in New Zealand, because during daylight savings time NZ is +13 HRs from UTC which can play havoc with any software that hasn't considered the possiblity of being greater than 12 hrs from Greenwich.

Answer (score 0):

It's to account for daylight savings time. As far as I know, the time you are putting in doesn't exist. Clocks are pushed forward at midnight on that day to 1am. I am not sure why it works in Java 7. Maybe THAT's the bug!

http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/brazil/brasilia

Daylight Savings Time occurs on the 3rd Sunday of October every year in Brazil which in 2041 happens to fall on October 20. It's not this specific date. It's any 3rd Sunday in October. Here are a few other examples:

```
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Brazil/East"));
        c.set(2017, Calendar.OCTOBER, 15, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        c.set(2019, Calendar.OCTOBER, 20, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
        c.set(2035, Calendar.OCTOBER, 21, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(c.getTime());
```

Overall, I would suggest NOT using the work-arounds suggested (except the one that uses Joda time and throws an exception), if the time you are trying to put in your system does not exist in the area/timezone of this application in real life (think of a daily disaster recovery job being scheduled to run at that time and never happening).

Comment: You cannot cure timezone data with setting the locale. Both are different subjects. The `Locale`-parameter in `Calendar`-class is only relevant for calendar week calculations, not for timezone data.

Comment: @MenoHochschild, I am aware of that, but Daylight Savings Time is calculated by the the 3rd Sunday in October which is a week calculation. Right? Please, explain if I am misunderstanding how that is not relevant and I will remove that from my answer :).

Comment: Well, the tzdb-repository uses internally some week calculations for special rules when to switch to daylight time. But this has nothing to do with the behaviour of `java.util.GregorianCalendar`. In that class, Locale-parameter is not used for timezone calculations. Just study the source code, and it is clear.